# How to use geom_text in line charts with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `geom_text` to plot the values in line graphs using ggplot2. However, the values in this chart type are scattered as follows:

[image: Graph Exemple]

I would like each value to be above each `geom_point` that corresponds to the Release value:

[image]

**CODE TO PLOT:**

```
ggplot(ReminderChangeLOCOnModules, aes(x=Release, y=Modified, group=Technique)) + 
ylab("Quantity") + 
geom_text(aes(label=Modified), position = position_dodge(width=0.8), hjust=-.25, size=3.5) + 
geom_line(aes(linetype = Technique, color=Technique), size=2) + 
geom_point(aes(color = Technique), size=5, stroke = 0, shape = 16) + 
scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid")) + 
scale_color_manual(values=c('#DC143C','#4169E1')) + 
theme_bw(base_size = 24) + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.title=element_blank())
```

**DATASET:**

```
Release,Technique,Added,Modified,Removed
v2,DOP,1415,13,6
v3,DOP,1485,14,18
v4,DOP,909,17,185
v2,CC,1150,4,0
v3,CC,1048,10,9
v4,CC,572,42,130
```

Comment: This looks like good place to use `vjust` instead of / in addition to `hjust`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the context of where this graphic is going, you can use `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` to move the text elements around. This has the desired output:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ReminderChangeLOCOnModules <- data.frame(Release = c("v2", "v3", "v4", "v2", "v3", "v4"),
                                         Technique = c("DOP", "DOP", "DOP", "CC", "CC", "CC"),
                                         Added = c(1415, 1485, 909, 1150, 1048, 572),
                                         Modified = c(13, 14, 17, 4, 10, 42),
                                         Removed = c(6, 18, 185, 0, 9, 130))


ggplot(ReminderChangeLOCOnModules, aes(x=Release, y=Modified, group=Technique)) + 
  ylab("Quantity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Modified), hjust=-.25, nudge_y = 2, nudge_x = -.1, size=3.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Technique, color=Technique), size=2) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Technique), size=5, stroke = 0, shape = 16) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#DC143C','#4169E1')) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 24) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image: RPlot]

Answer (score 2):

Here I use `vjust` to put the text 1.5 text lines above the points. The other most common way to adjust text's vertical position is with `nudge_y`, which adds a fixed amount in coordinate space. (ie vjust scales to the height of the text, while nudge_y scales to the units on the y axis.)

```
ggplot(ReminderChangeLOCOnModules, aes(x=Release, y=Modified, group=Technique)) + 
  ylab("Quantity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Modified), vjust = -1.5, size=3.5) +     # <---- here
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Technique, color=Technique), size=2) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Technique), size=5, stroke = 0, shape = 16) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#DC143C','#4169E1')) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 24) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.title=element_blank())
```